# When using Kafka High Level ConsumerConnector where will offsets be kept?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

As the new document suggests, Kafka itself will take care of offsets management when using High Level API by default. But When I create a ConsumerConnector as below, it still requires me to provide zookeeper.connect property.

```
_consumerConnector = Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(consumerConfig);
```

Is it true that in this case, it is still zookeeper who manages offset? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As of Kafka `0.9` offsets are stored in an special topic `__consumer_offsets`. However, `KafkaConsumer` does still depend on ZK (for other reasons). In future releases, the dependency to ZK will be removed completely.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's still the old high level consumer API. You can still manage offsets with the old Scala consumer in Kafka but it requires offsets.storage to be set to Kafka and you'll still need zookeeper.

The "new" consumer api is a java api and does indeed use Kafka for offset storage and doesn't require a zookeeper connection config. That api is documented [here](http://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html).

Comment: Yes, I find in the new api document it says that when using KafkaConsumer the offsets can be managed by kafka. But it did not mention what will happen when using ConsumerConnector. Do you have any idea about this? Thank you!

Comment: I believe that will be the same as the old consumer and depend on zookeeper